# Bluetooth headset turns off when Skype call ends

Tags: skype, bluetooth, usb-headset

For about 6 months, I haven't been able to use Skype because when I end a Skype call, my Plantronics Callisto headset gets turned off. I'm paralyzed so I can't turn it on manually. I have a Sony VAIO computer running Windows 7. I have updated my Bluetooth dongle software, uninstalled and reinstalled Skype and uninstalled Skype and gone back to an earlier version; all to no avail. Neither Plantronics nor Skype technical support are interested in looking into this problem for me.